# Black screen no log on after install windows 10 on alienware computer

Tags: windows-8, windows-10-preview, black-screen-of-death

My son has an Alienware computer w/Windows 8, which is only 6 months old. He installed Windows 10 last week and a black screen appeared that contained a cursor, but no login text boxes.

We have tried restarting, etc., and the Alienware logo pops up but then the hard drive loads a black screen where the only thing showing is the aforementioned cursor.

We are not computer techs and have no clue what we should try.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm assuming you upgraded from windows 8 to 10 and it's not fresh install? In my case it was a driver problem - Boot windows in safe mode with networking and go to device manager and check what drivers are missing and update them (in my case it was my graphics driver)

Comment: I'm not sure how to start in safe mode as it doesn't give any options just a black screen on restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem(upgrading from Win7), and yes it is a driver problem. First problem is to get into safe mode. In Win10 F8 usually does not work- so there is no easy way to get into safe mode. I had to unplug the power cable while loading windows. The next time it gave me repair and troubleshooting options and I could get into safe mode (which was visible).
Started msconfig and disabled ALL non Microsoft services (by first hiding all MS services) and ALL startup programs. After restart Screen was normal. Then, finding which service was the culprit was a LOT of re-starts (and enabling some of the services and testing), but I found it. In my case it was a Dell program messing with my login(!!)